# Как сделать адаптивную карту 2gis?

Tags: html, css

Карта загружается по ссылке, не знаю, как её заадаптивить. max-width 100% не помогает.
Пример карты тут http://apple36.ru/kak-nas-najti .

Answer (score 1):

Надо жестко задать ширину → `width: 100%;` либо если не поможет → `width: 100vw`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?